# Cloned package not getting compiled

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I cloned a package from Github to my workspace and tried to catkin_make. But apparently, just that folder is being skipped and is not getting compiled. I tried deleting build and devel, nothing worked. No errors are thrown out, just that new folder is not getting compiled.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323773/cloned-package-not-getting-compiled./) by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-22**:
Can you describe the structure of your work space and exactly where you have cloned the package to. We don't have enough information to be able to help you.

**Comment by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on 2019-05-22**:
It's a standard ROS workspace with an src folder holding all the packages. Currently, I have three packages, one created by me and two others cloned from Github. One of the cloned folders in not getting compiled. I guess the structure is fine.
Thank you for your response.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
We don't do guesses here on ROS Answers.

What is the output of `tree -d -L 1 /path/to/your/workspace` (if you get an error, make sure to run `sudo apt install tree` and try again)?

---

Edit: also:

> I cloned a package from Github

can you link to the repository? I have a suspicion this is a rosbuild package, which will not be built by Catkin.

**Comment by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on 2019-05-22**:
I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new to this. Excuse me if my questions are plain basic.
I tried the tree to get the workspace structure. `tree: Invalid level, must be greater than 0.` is the message I got. This is what I ran `tree -d -L1 /home/user/workspace`.
And the repository from which I cloned that package is https://github.com/lrse/ros-keyboard

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
A space was missing between the `L` and the `1`, I've updated the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out that the package was actually getting compiled but with a different name as compared to the folder name itself because of that different name being tagged in package.xml by the developer, which was not mentioned anywhere. That's the reason I couldn't find the package when I used the folder name, which is normally the case.
Thank you for your time.

---

Originally posted by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) with karma: 26 on 2019-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-24**:
Glad you got to the bottom of this. It's a good way to learn that the folder names do not necessarily match package names.